# Python 3.x - TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this problem in my code and I can not solve, since it works in version 2.7, but 3.4 already of this message.

In my code I have methods:
Method 1

```
def getFacebookPageFeedData(page_id, access_token, num_statuses):
parameters = "/?access_token=%s" % (access_token, num_statuses)
```

Method 2

```
def scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(page_id, access_token):
```

In this second method I have:

```
statuses = getFacebookPageFeedData(page_id, access_token, 100)
```

But every time I run the code, this error is displayed:

```
parameters = "/?access_token=%s" % (access_token, num_statuses)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What should I do to the version 3.4 this parameter passing through?

Comment: The string has one `%s`, and you're interpolating two objects. Did you read the error message and look at the code it points out?

Comment: Yeah. It points to 
    parameters = "/?access_token=%s" % (access_token, num_statuses)

Comment: That's right. Did you look over that code? Do you know what it means? Did you Google the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put as many `%s` as variables you want to insert in the string.
I think you want only to insert the access token:

```
parameters = "/?access_token=%s" % (access_token)
```

If you printed parameters the result would be:

/?access_token=x (where x is the variable access_token)

Answer (score 0):

This exception will be raised in Python 2.x *and* Python 3.x.

If you have only a single `%s` in your string, then you can only have
a single argument after the `%` that follows your string:

```
print('Hello %s' % 'world')
```

On the other hand, if you have *two* arguments following your string as you do, you need two string formatting characters (like `%s`) in your string:

```
print('%s %s' % ('Hello', 'world'))
```

Based on a little googling, it looks like what you need in your case is:

```
parameters = "/?access_token=%s&limit=%s" % (access_token, num_statuses)
```

One really great piece of study material for learning about string formatting can be found [here](https://pyformat.info). And of course, [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) are a great place to start as well.